# Conversion journaled to APFS under Mojave

Tags: recovery, apfs

I would like to update from Mojave to Catalina.

MAC is late 2012 and OS is Mojave 10.14.2

Update fails because SSD is not APFS.

I have read disk can be converted, using Disk Utility in recovery mode.
Function to convert disk should be either in the edit menu or under a conversion button.

Unfortunately, I Can find neither edit menu nor conversion button.

The system is in recovery mode. There is a convert button which gets enabled selecting disk1, but the effect is different from what I expected, as shown

[image]

[image][image: mac os][image: ssd]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please see [ask] for tips on asking questions here.  Also, your title states "Mojave" but you've tagged the question as "Catalina".  Please [edit] your question to add the missing info, including what you've done already to resolve the problem.  - From Review

Comment: That recovery partition is too old to be able to handle APFS. By the looks of the coloured dots, top left of each window it's running OS X 10.9 or older. You will need to give us more detail on what Mac it is & what was the last OS that was on it. If you are trying to get from something as old as Snow Leopard to Mojave you need El Capitan first - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos

Comment: If you boot from recovery using Option-⌘-R instead of ⌘-R, do you get the Mojave or Catalina recovery mode?

Comment: nice! Using option-⌘-R I get Disk utility ver 19.0 and edit menu is there. I have deactivated MAC volume and converted it to APFS. Now I have a container that includes MAC volume. I'm not able to activate it. MAC volume is active but container not. Restarting won't boot. Hope I have not been too hasty

Comment: [solved] no way to make mac start from SSD, so I Have created a bootable USB key with Catalina on it. Running mac from USB and installing Catalina on SSD, everything went fine with no data loss. Thanks for your time